# DevExpress DashboardLoading get data from MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am new to use DevExpress methods to create a Dashboard for web application on asp.net. I am not getting a good enough example in DashboardLoading method from DevExpress of how to get data directly from MS SQL Server. Have anyone successfully and have a example code for that? It seems like they are using XML, txt, or other kind of files to get data to put in Dashboard. I don't want that. One of them mentioned to use Stream but it required to create a filestream in database and that's not what I am looking for. Here is example from DevExpress that was for xml, http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4761.

Here is my example so far,

```
public partial class Viewer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uid = AD.GetUserID() + "_p";
        Tin.ActiveDirectory.ADSearch ad = new Tin.ActiveDirectory.ADSearch("tdcc");

        if (ad.Check_If_Member_Of_AD_Functional_Group(uid, "NEACntrlRmAdm-G") | ad.Check_If_Member_Of_AD_Functional_Group(uid, "NEAWinAdm-G"))
        {
            //authorized
        }
        else
        {
            //Response.Redirect("Denied.asp")
        }

        ASPxDashboardViewer1.DashboardId = "MirrorDashboard";

    }

    protected void ASPxDashboardViewer1_DashboardLoading(object sender, 
            DevExpress.DashboardWeb.DashboardLoadingEventArgs e)
    {

        //check the identifier of the required dashboard
        if(e.DashboardId == "MirrorDashboard")
        {

            //To get data from SQL Serve to load the Dashboard

        }

    }

    protected void ASPxDashboardViewer1_ConfigureDataConnection(object sender, DevExpress.DashboardWeb.ConfigureDataConnectionWebEventArgs e)
    {

        //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GM"].ConnectionString);
        var parameters = e.ConnectionParameters as MsSqlConnectionParameters;


        if (parameters != null)
        {
            parameters.AuthorizationType = MsSqlAuthorizationType.SqlServer;
            parameters.DatabaseName = "GM";
            parameters.ServerName = "*****";
            parameters.UserName="****";
            parameters.Password="****";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, they keep only the database connection settings in the XML file. The data is always loaded from the SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how Dashboard works. Check out their documentation [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Dashboard/CustomDocument12137). You first have to create the dashboard and wire it up to your SQL Server then copy the XML file to your WEB app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code:

```
try
        {

            if (e.DashboardId == "ASPxDashboardViewer1")
            {
                string definitionPath = "";
                string dashboardDefinition;

                switch (option)
                {
                    case "A": definitionPath = Server.MapPath("~/A.xml"); break;
                    case "B": definitionPath = Server.MapPath("~/B.xml"); break;
                }

                dashboardDefinition = File.ReadAllText(definitionPath);

                e.DashboardXml = dashboardDefinition;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (IsCallback)
            {
                DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallback.RedirectOnCallback("Signout.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Signout.aspx");
            }
        }
```